# Teste unitários de um BackgroundService

Tags: c#, injeção-de-dependência, background-services

Preciso implementar testes unitários em um BackgroundService. Já li muitos post e links a respeito, mas nada foi muito esclarecedor. Como exemplo, criei um Worker que recebe um Parametro por injeção de dependência, que contem uma propriedade do tipo DateTime e ele deve definir qual é o turno do horário.

```
namespace MessageWorker;

public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly Parametros _parametros;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, Parametros parametros)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _parametros = parametros;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            string turno;
            if (_parametros.DataEHora.Hour < 12)
                turno = "Turno 1";
            else
                turno = "Turno 2";
            
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time} - {turno}", DateTimeOffset.Now, turno);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

E o código do Program que faz o registro do HostedService

```
using MessageWorker;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services => 
    {
        services.AddSingleton(new Parametros
        {
            DataEHora = new DateTime(2024, 1, 5, 9, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
        });
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Ao rodar via Visual Studio, o código funciona e consigo ver a mensagem, mas como posso escrever um teste unitário para esse Worker e testar o seu retorno? Qualquer exemplo me ajuda. Obrigado.

Comment: olá veja se isso ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56644654/how-can-i-write-unit-test-for-my-background-service

Answer (score 1):

Consegui implementar da seguinte forma.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestIsRunning()
{
    var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<Worker>>();

    var worker = new Worker(loggerMock.Object, new Parametros { DataEHora = new DateTime(2024, 1, 5, 9, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) });
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    await worker.StartAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    await Task.Delay(3000); // Wait for some time to let the worker log information
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel(); // Stop the worker
    cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();

    loggerMock.Verify(
        x => x.Log(
            LogLevel.Information,
            It.IsAny<EventId>(),
            It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((o, t) => o.ToString().Contains("Turno 1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)),
            It.IsAny<Exception>(),
            It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception?, string>>()),
        Times.AtLeastOnce);
}
```

Bem simples e me fornece o resultado que eu precisava